# Error using Google Studio Formula with Case

Tags: formula, looker-studio

I am getting a formula error with the following logic and not sure why?

```
CASE
   WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Page, "/agencies/") THEN "Agency" 
END
```

Error:

> Invalid formula

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Comment: As noted below the question is **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo** due to incorrect [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7020724) syntax

Comment: This question is linked in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426784/should-reproducible-questions-which-becomes-non-reproducible-be-closed-and-or-d). cc:@Nimantha

Comment: If the above still causes a syntax error, hownid this *not* reproducible, @Nimantha ? Is `CONTAINS_TEXT` now usable in a `CASE` so the behaviour the OP describes would no longer happen?

Comment: A correction on the statement - the CASE now works as expected - thus the above CASE is valid and would display the results as expected

Comment: So it *was* reproducible at the time and not a typo, @Nimantha ?

Comment: Not entirely sure, I used Regex at the time. The invalid formula tends to come up occasionally if a data source has recently been updated or a random error - Even for valid formulas it pops up - sometimes if the internet connection is slow or has been lost

Comment: Invalid formula is a typo as it still shows up occasionally for certain users for valid formulas - Looker Studio is web based and sometimes it's a result of connectivity (I've had the issue when the data source schema has changed - where I guess it was a general error text message shown)

Comment: I'll need to double check, but here is an example [Any calculated field comes up "Invalid Formula"](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/thread/15367854/any-calculated-field-comes-up-invalid-formula). Sometimes it's a server side bug in that instance

Comment: This question is **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo** After some digging it looks like the `CONTAINS_TEXT` function was (always?) supported at the time, thus as noted above - the "Invalid Formula" error message was and is **Not Reproducible**. Here is a [YouTube video from 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_M0bjZatoPE) where it worked as expected. I also checked my answers - there is one from [November 2020](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/thread/82347742) that shows that the CASE statement used in that question should have worked as expected and still does.

Comment: @ThomA: I've added a few more comments looking through...The `CONTAINS_TEXT` function worked as expected in `CASE` at the time and it still does. The "Invalid Formula" error is **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo** as it should have worked as expected. I've added links to questions where it worked as expected at the time (see above and this [June 2019 article](https://michaelhoweely.com/2019/06/28/creating-custom-search-query-categories-using-case-statements-in-data-studio/). I had initially voted to close the question as **Needs Details or Clarity** in February 2022

Comment: All this now and then discussions seems a bit strange. Surely this question asks about the state of the software then, not now. Reproducibility tests should be performed with a past version (which might be difficult next to impossible with cloud based services). If the problem was fixed in the meantime one could maybe add a small note somewhere.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution: The official [Looker Studio Forum](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/threads?&max_results=100) has numerous posts on issues that are seemingly **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo** some of which sound very specific showing an image and an error code. Whenever I see a post like this I quickly try and recreate the scenario and it tends to be not reproducible and I move on (I remember doing so here as well in 2020) leaving a comment requesting for a [mre], ideally a publicly shared report with data (it might sound like a lot of steps, but it takes ~15 minutes)

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution - "*Reproducibility tests should be performed with a past version (which might be difficult next to impossible with cloud based services)*". Yes - I encountered this early on when answering Looker Studio questions, where users would state that they followed the exact steps but it didn't work. I started adding both a publicly editable Looker Studio Looker report as well as a GIF of the process in all my answers. Being web based also has certain unexpected and random issues which a browser refresh usually fixes, as with any other web based service.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724),

> WHEN conditions can include one or more supported comparison functions. See below.

Only a few formulas are supported inside `WHEN` condition clause and `CONTAINS_TEXT` isn't one of them. Use `IN` instead:

> IN

> Returns true if the input field contains any of the the listed values. Both the field and list values must be of the same type. IN matches complete values and is case-sensitive. For partial value or case insensitive matching, use REGEXP_MATCH.

```
CASE
   WHEN Page IN ("/agencies/") THEN "Agency" 
END
```

For partial match,

```
CASE
   WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Page, "(?i).*\\/agencies\\/.*") THEN "Agency" 
END
```

Comment: I tried this but no dice
 
CASE
   WHEN Page IN ("/agencies") THEN "Agencies"
   WHEN Page IN ("/solicitations") THEN "Solicitations" 
   WHEN Page IN ("/contract-cehicles") THEN "Contract Vehicles"
   WHEN Page IN ("/contracts") THEN "Contracts" 
ELSE
   "Other"
END

Comment: @PinkstonMatt `Page` needs to be a exact match to `/agencies`. If not, use regex.

Comment: After some digging, it looks like the error message "Invalid Formula" is (& was) **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo** for `CONTAINS_TEXT` function in `CASE`. Sources [YouTube video from 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_M0bjZatoPE); One of my answers from [November 2020](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/thread/82347742) that shows that the CASE statement used in that question should have worked as expected and still does; An article from [June 2019](https://michaelhoweely.com/2019/06/28/creating-custom-search-query-categories-using-case-statements-in-data-studio/)